# git diff on a file that is in .gitignore but has been added for tracking

Tags: git

For a file

> config/config.py

That file is in .gitignore I need to make changes to add to my own clone. However it is not desirable to change the .gitignore itself: we want most users not to see this file.

So I did

```
git add -f config/config.py
```

However

```
git diff config/config.py
```

shows nothing.

**Correction** I had stated in original version that

```
git status
```

shows nothing: that is not true it does show

```
new file:   config/config.py
```

So it appears the surprise were only with the **git diff** command?

(Off topic a bit: generally the whole .gitignore / tracked vs untracked is a surprisingly tricky/painful process.  I have looked at a number of SOF's on this topic and they do not lend confidence here.)

Comment: Weird. I just created a similar scenario and `git add -f` did the job for me.

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't tracked already? Use `git ls-files` to see all tracked files. Try `git add -f -v config/config.py`: the `-v` option tells `git add` to display a message when actually adding a file.

Comment: @MatthieuMoy It is tracked - my original statement was incorrect . But git diff still does not show anything.

Comment: because it ignores the local copy and have nothing to compare it to? is there any output if you do git diff HEAD config/config.py?

Comment: @cerkiewny  your command does not work would you pls edit for specific syntax  "HEAD: no such path in the working tree"

Comment: yea i forgot the branch needs to be before the file

Comment: ok thx. Now what happens: the ENTIRE file is showing in diff. this is a PITA.

Comment: yes, what other behaviour you are expecting ?

Comment: @cerkiewny  I need a normal diff - between the changes I made and the version in the repo.   Maybe it were not clear: diff is showing a NEW file so all lines are displayed, not the changes.

Comment: there is not previous state in the repository otherwise it would say "modified" not a "new file"

Comment: @cerkiewny  Oh I see. It looks like when I followed another SOF and did "git rm --cached config/config.py"  (but then I did git checkout on it to revert that process) it apparently got the history messed up?  This whole process is beyond reasonable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77334/discussion-between-cerkiewny-and-javadba).

Answer (score 1):

`git diff` shows the difference between the staging area (aka index) and the working tree. You have just added your file to the staging area, so it is perfectly normal that `git diff` shows nothing. You want to run

```
git diff HEAD
```

instead. This will show the diff between the file and `HEAD` which means "the last commit". If the file was not present in `HEAD`, then the diff will show the whole file.

It seems that you ran `git rm --cached` and did a commit previously, hence the file is not there in `HEAD`. You did a mistake previously, and trying to repair this mistake can be more dangerous if you do not understand what you are doing. If you want to try, then learn about rewriting history in Git.

If you want to see the diff with a commit past in history, then run

```
git diff <commit-id>
```

This is completely unrelated from the fact that the file is in `.gitignore`.

Comment: He also deleted his local history of the file with git rm --cached add the note about it and you have my +1

Comment: Actually this whole process is still not working.  What should be done instead of "git add -f <file>" ?  That is not remembering that the file *already* exists.  So the "git diff <file>" does not work correctly - it loses the history.